# How to make a customed value works in output tag on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, output

How to make a customed value works in output tag on IE?
I have used the HTML5 Forms polyfill from he source: https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/html5Forms.js, but the value is not changing on output tag.

This is my example of html code:

```html
<label for="budget" id="clientBudget">
<label id="range">Age:
<output id="rangevalue" onforminput="this.value = rangeEl.value"> 18</output>
<span id="priceIcon">years</span>
</label>
<input type="range" name="rangeEl" value="18" id="range" min="18" max="120" steps="1" onchange="rangevalue.value=value" title="Range"/>
</label>
```

Thanks in advance for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

Since IE does not support the output element there is no value property to update.

You could try a ternary operator to check to see if the 'value' property exists if it does update it else update innerHTML.

```
  <input type="range" name="rangeEl" value="18" id="range" min="18" max="120" steps="1" onchange="!rangevalue.value ? rangevalue.innerHTML = this.value:rangevalue.value=this.value;" title="Range" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/egfu4dtk/

Comment: Thank you @SeanWessell, it really works in Edit Fiddle, but in my file on IE+10 still doesn't. I supposed that I had a styling problem with css file.
I have used:
#rangevalue[onforminput="!rangevalue.value ? rangevalue.innerHTML = this.value:rangevalue.value=this.value;"]{
 display:visible;
 color:red;
}
On IE+10 the default value is seen as red color, but still not working.